# Why might ergativity be correlated with polypersonal agreement?

Tags: ergativity, polypersonalism

The [Wikipedia article on polypersonal agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polypersonal_agreement) states that it "has also been correlated with ergativity." This is certainly true of Basque, the only ergative language I have any familiarity with.

The Wikipedia article doesn't give many examples of ergative languages that also exhibit polypersonal agreement, so perhaps this is a weak correlation.

It's hard to imagine a process by which ergative languages would tend towards polypersonal agreement, but could anyone suggest why such a thing might occur?

Comment: The majority of Pama-Nyungan languages are ergative, and I'm not aware of any that show 'polypersonal agreement'. I think it would be fair to request a reference for that statement on WP.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not necessarily asserting Wikipedia is correct.

Comment: Mayan languages are both polypersonal and ergative.

Comment: Georgian has both inconsistent polypersonalism and inconsistent ergativity.